Add an action to commit, to be executed post-pull - something like a one-time only git post-merge hook?
Is it possible to furnish a single commit with something akin to a pull-completion-handler?
Consider the situation:

I make some dramatic changes to some "meta-structures" in the repository. By "meta" I mean things that can't be committed, but are elementary to the project.

Everyone who pulls that commit will have to perform a certain migration, otherwise the project won't build. In my case, the migration would probably "just" consist of some script.


I want to automate the script-running part, in that it should happen after that specific commit has been pulled (i.e. merged into the local repository).
Thus post-merge hooks would not be the correct place, since they would be run every time.
Of course, one solution would be to have some flag didPerformMigration.

I should mention: we are using gitlab. That might change things.

There is no. And even if there was one it wouldn't be run automatically. Security: the remote repository shouldn't run code on the user's hosts without the user consent; users should be allowed to inspect and agree before running the code. So the solution to you problem is: add a script to the commit, push and document that users must run the script manually.

Gitlab's docs say that server-side hooks are available.  Those hooks can execute programs written in any language (bash, perl, python, etc.).  Inside your (eg. post-receive) hook script, you could parse the commit message for certain magic keywords indicating your big change.

@AndyJ I think server-side hooks would not be sufficient, since the script basically needs to update certain programs, and reconfigure others. So I think the best would indeed be what phd suggests: tell everyone in slack to rtds (run the darling script)
